# Is there a way to use regex in an R script to pull data from in between two characters with accounting for inconsistent spacing?

Tags: r, regex

I am currently trying to pull data from a pdf using the str_match function which is working well. This is an example:

```
    values[[18]] <- str_match(Sprout_textNoLines, "Business Description: (.*?) Renter or Owned:")[,2]
```

Sprout_textNoLines is just a paragraph of all the characters in the pdf, not separated by lines. The particular case that I'm parsing here is

```
    Business Description: Federal and State Construction Renter or Owned:
```

The str_match call that I showed earlier returns "Federal and State Construction" which is exactly what I need. However, I am finding cases where some of the pdfs are different and the inputs on the lines won't be separated by a space for example:

```
    Business Description:Federal and State Construction Renter or Owned:
```

There is no space between Description: and Federal here so the earlier function call will just pull back NA here because Business Description: (.*?) Renter or Owned:. I need to automate this process so is there a regex that could accomplish something similar to

```
    values[[18]] <- str_match(Sprout_textNoLines, "Business Description: (.*?) Renter or Owned:")[,2]
```

but with adding regex to the (.*?) to account for variability in the amount of spaces between the string that I want to pull and the strings that precede and follow it?

Comment: Can you show reproducible example

Comment: How about `str_match(Sprout_textNoLines, "Business Description:\\s*(.*?) Renter or Owned:")[,2]`?  `\\s*` means zero or more spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
str_match(Sprout_textNoLines, "Business Description:\\s*(.*?)\\s*Renter or Owned:")[,2]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/77cXMI/1)

The part that is changed is `\s*(.*?)\s*` that matches 0 or more whitespaces (`\s*`), then captures any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then again 0 or more whitespaces are matched.